# The Power of Red - A "Who Am I" Riddle

Tags: riddle, rhyme

**Hi! This is my first riddle. Have fun trying to solve it!**

```
My name can be one word or two;
it really doesn’t matter.
And if you drop me to the floor,
I might make a clatter.

I do everything I can do
with the power of red,
but even though this red cannot be seen,
my usage throughout houses has spread.

The relative versions of all directions, such as
north, south, east, and west
is how things can move
when my buttons are pressed.

If you are “infinity gone wrong”,
I will help your box run.
And using me will help you see
everything under the sun.

I'll help you change the “river”
and then I’ll make a ding,
and then I’ll change the “area” too
of a more complex thing.

Now I’ve given you plenty of clues,
none of them being lies,
so all you have to do is guess: 
who am I?
```

Answer (score 14):

Nice first riddle! Unfortunately there are two hints I could not explain. :/
Nevertheless, I think you are..

> a **remote control**.

---

```
My name can be one word or two;
it really doesn’t matter.
```

> Remote or remote control.

```
And if you drop me to the floor,
I might make a clatter.
```

> The body of remote controls is generally made of plastic, which makes a clatter when dropped on a hard surface.

```
I do everything I can do
with the power of red,
```

> Most remote controls work using infrared light which is just outside the range of visibility to the naked eye.

```
but even though this red cannot be seen,
my usage throughout houses has spread.
```

> Over the past decades as technology has advanced, more and more people have had access to remote controlled televisions (though this a bit "outdated" now, lol).

```
The relative versions of all directions, such as
north, south, east, and west
is how things can move
when my buttons are pressed.
```

> This is a bit unclear for me, but I think it hints towards how you generally switch channels back and forth by pressing the up and down buttons on the remote control, and increase or decrease volume by pressing left or right.

```
If you are “infinity gone wrong”,
```

> Not sure what this hints at.

```
I will help your box run.
And using me will help you see
everything under the sun.
```

> You use the remote control to turn your television on and switch channels, allowing you to watch whatever it is you feel like watching **(assuming you are paying enough dolla to have access to the relevant channels of course ;P)**.

```
I'll help you change the “river”
```

> River and channel can by synonymous. You use the remote control to change channels on your television.

```
and then I’ll make a ding,
```

> Not sure about this. Maybe it's because I haven't watched television in years. Do remote controls or televisions make sound effects when you change channels? Maybe it refers to the static-y noise televisions make when they turn on. (Or I suppose sometimes when you switch channels?)

```
and then I’ll change the “area” too
of a more complex thing.
```

> Not sure what this hints at.

```
Now I’ve given you plenty of clues,
none of them being lies,
so all you have to do is guess: 
who am I?
```

> A remote control!

Comment: Regarding area: some more complex TV may be able to pick their source (multiple cables, DVD reader, ...). That may be it...

Comment: Or maybe "area" refers to a screen which changes when you switch channels and "a more complex thing" refers to a TV

Comment: [Nfinity gone wrong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comcast#Comcast_Cable_.28Xfinity.29)

Comment: Almost there! Correct answer, just come up with the correct explanations for the "infinity gone wrong" and "area of a more complex thing" and put them in your answer and then I'll mark it as correct! Sorry about the "ding" part, some remotes may make a ding while others may not :)

Comment: river:channel :: area:volume

Comment: I agree with @humn that the infinity clue hints towards Xfinity by Comcast, tough clue since it is region specific as far as I know.

Comment: Area might be referring to changing the screen size, or maybe creating a PIP window? Thinking area in the mathematical sense

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. I still don't understand the "infinity gone wrong" hint. What does "gone wrong" mean, assuming "infinity" refers to Comcast's Xfinity? As for the clue about area, I think I understand now. I think it means that when you press a button to change channel the remote control will ding and then the screen on the TV will change. @TheGreenFrog

Comment: "Gone wrong" is a crossword clue that hints at spelling _corruption_, in this case twice over as one letter is dropped and another is changed

Comment: @humn Ah that would make sense. Thank you. I never really did crosswords. :D I'm sorry TheGreenFrog I know it can be annoying when someone has the answer and most of the clues solved and is struggling with just a few that are left.

Comment: @humn That's not the reason I wrote "infinity gone wrong". :| Think about what happens when you get something _wrong_ on a test. But it does mean "Xfinity".

Comment: @TheGreenFrog it's infinity with the 'in' crossed out?

Comment: @computhomas Nope. What are there lots of on a test with lots of **wrong** answers?

Comment: @TheGreenFrog X's? That's what I was referring to, somebody X'ed out the "in" portion of infinity? If not I have no idea

Comment: @computhomas Yes! You got it! Infinity turns into Xfinity because it "went wrong" and got an X on it instead of the "in"! :D

Comment: @SpiritFryer Just edit the infinity -> Xfinity explanation from the previous 3  comments into your answer, and then all you have left is the area part! (because your explanation of the "area of a more complex thing" part is incorrect)

Comment: Hmm, but to be honest I still don't understand what 'If you are “infinity gone wrong”, I will help your box run.' means, lol. Am I just being dumb?

Comment: @SpiritFryer You can see that "infinity" and "Xfinity" look similar. The point is that "infinity went wrong", so it got an X mark on it. With the X mark, **in**finity becomes **X**finity. (This is one of the hardest clues in the riddle.) Now just edit it into your answer and figure out the "area of a more complex thing" part. (Your explanation of that part was incorrect.)

Comment: @SpiritFryer (And Xfinity can install cable boxes for television, and remote controls do things for them, like changing the channel.)

Comment: @TheGreenFrog Ah ok, I see. Sorry you needed to help so much before I understood it finally. I will do the edit and think on the last hint tomorrow as it's 2am for me here (tomorrow being technically today for me...).